# CSS word-break: break-all don't working with links

Tags: html, css

I'm having a responsible problem with my website. All adapts correctly to the size of screen, except for the `a` link tag. It keeps long and exceding the dimension of screen, I've tried this:

```
a
{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

But the link, instead of displaying like:

```
http://somesite
thatoverflowcontent
.com
```

...Continues displaying like that and extending the size of content, overflowing the screen:

```
http://somesitethatoverflowcontent.com
```

Why is `word-break: break-all` don't working in this case?

Comment: Perhaps the `<a>` element has a `display: block` or `display: inline-block` style that causes it to block up? Can you show all of the styles for the `<a>` element?

Comment: @LambdaNinja Added `display: inline-block` rule and worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I actually thought it would work the other way around, but I'm glad it helped you nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Added the `display: inline-block` rule on `a` element and worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `<a>` tag is `display: inline` by default, and you can't set a `width` for inline elements.

**[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)**,

> word-break will create a break at the exact place where text would otherwise overflow its container

Considering you can't apply a width to an `inline` element, the text would never overflow the container unless you change the `display` (in addition to setting a `width`):

```css
a, p {
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 10%;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://somesitethatoverflowcontent.com">http://somesitethatoverflowcontent.com</a>
<p>http://somesitethatoverflowcontent.com</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Or: `a { overflow-wrap: break-word; }`.